# Check the project availability in current workspace of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Using java program how to check that particular project (eq `DemoProject`) is available in current workspace of eclipse (the program should work on any machines also it should not system specific)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a Java program running from within Eclipse itself, as a plugin, you can try getting the project with:

```
 ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getWorkspaceRoot().getProject("projectName")
```

, using the [`org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.java.htm)  and test that resource (the [`org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.java.htm).

Comment: I am getting the this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed. Can u plz help me in this...

Comment: @Rahul: that thread could help: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg44995.html

Comment: @Rahul: what is your context: are you developing a plugin for Eclipse or for an independent RCP application?

Comment: I want a java program which will help me to get the name of current workspace and all the projects which are in current workspace..i want to use some conditional logic(if..else) on that.It is a small part of eclipse plugin..

Comment: @Rahul: you need to be in an eclipse plugin for that: you cannot do it as an external independent Java program outside of your Eclipse (which contains the workspace). But if it is, as you mention, a part of an Eclipse plugin, then my answer stands, ... except if the Workspace is closed (which happens when you try out your plugin from within your Eclipse by opening a new Runtime session (see the thread I mention): then no workspace is yet opened.